# Error installing gnupg2 dependency libusb using homebrew

Tags: macos, libusb, gnupg

I'm installing gnupg2 using homebrew on mac osx and getting errors intstalling the dependency libusb.

```
brew install gpg2
```

....

```
==> Installing gnupg2 dependency: libusb
==> Downloading http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/libusb/libusb-1.0/libusb-1.0.9/libusb-1.0.9.tar.bz2
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/libusb-1.0.9.tar.bz2
==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/libusb/1.0.9
==> make install
os/darwin_usb.c:1749: error: old-style parameter declarations in prototyped function definition
os/darwin_usb.c:1749: error: expected '{' at end of input
make[1]: *** [libusb_1_0_la-darwin_usb.lo] Error 1
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, fixed it by installing the XCode command line tools (previously was using gcc standalone package)